# Can't find the right display resolution

Tags: virtualbox, display, screen, display-resolution

I have a problem that Ubuntu does not have the screen resolution that matches my computer "that is 1920x1080". The available resolutions are way bigger or smaller than my screen. Please also note that I am using Ubuntu in a virtual machine "which is Oracle virtual box" Please help me if you have any idea on how to fix this and thank you!!

Update: Installing virtual box extension won't change the screen resolution. Nor does the full screen option do. Is there a way to manually add (1920x1080) resolution?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running inside VirtualBox, there is no need to manually set Ubuntu's resolution.  If you install the VirtualBox Guest Extensions inside Ubuntu, it will automatically change its resolution to match the size of VirtualBox's window, so you can just drag the edge of the window to resize it.  If you want to make it full screen, press Right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Here's a guide on how to install the guest extensions:
https://www.tecmint.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/